# (ssg-wsg) What is the encryption algorithm for payload encryption used in SSG-WSG Developer Portal?

Tags: api

I tried to create an MTLS app according to [the guide](https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/credential) listed in the SSG-WSG website, and was trying to use an payload encrypted API but I'm not sure how I should encrypt my payload.

The [Skills Passport API swagger](https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/4ZCqa7uABJeR6vtKUjsxyx/group/6NqcljmEXinhh5SP9drNXL#) mentioned that it requires AES but what about the Algorithm used?

I read their [FAQ site](https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/faq) but I couldn't find any related articles to what I'm looking for. Can you please help with my question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see from their [GitHub](https://github.com/ssg-wsg/sampleUtil/tree/master/encryptdecrypt) page, encryption algorithm is AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING and initialization vector is SSGAPIInitVector.

I have tested it out earlier and it seems to be working.